# How to write specific rows to specific RegionServer?

Tags: hbase

I have two region servers, `RS1` and `RS2`. I want to ensure that all the rows with key starting with letter less than `M` go to regions in `RS1` and then rest into regions in `RS2`.

How to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should take a look to http://hbase.apache.org/book/regions.arch.html, the HBase book has great information about regions and splits.

---

Regarding your question, you just need to create a table with 2 regions and assign each one to each Region server. To create a table with 2 regions you'll just have to provide one split point (by default, only 1 region will be created)

```
$ hbase shell
hbase> create 'my_table', 'f1', SPLITS=> ['M']
```

Once done, head to your master to check your table regions `http://my_master:60010/table.jsp?name=my_table`

```
Name | Region Server | Start Key | End Key | Requests
my_table,,1420361349896.82ef0d5d63ecc37bc076f51f6a7d3074. | my_rs_1:60030 | | M | 0
my_table,M,1420361349897.9ce694c69f1b177a1db2dce224febb92. | my_rs_2:60030 | M | | 0
```

You'll probably have one region assigned for each regionserver automatically, but in case both regions are on the same regionserver (i.e. my_rs_1) you can move one of the regions to the other:

```
hbase> move '9ce694c69f1b177a1db2dce224febb92','my_rs_2,60020,1414964067589'
```

Please notice that move command requires you to provide the encoded region name and the full server id (you can find a list of your region servers ids here `http://my_master:60010/master-status`)

Then again, head to your master `http://my_master:60010/table.jsp?name=my_table` to check that the region has been successfully assigned to the other regionserver.